# How to send push notification Firebase direct from app by code

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send a push notification when an event happens in my app, **without using the Firebase console** for this.
Can I send a request by json to the server? And if so, how? Because I have difficulties in this part.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [send upstream messages from your app to Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/upstream). But you will need your own [app server to respond to those messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/upstream#receive_xmpp_messages_on_the_app_server). I recommend reading the [documentation on the role of these servers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server).

Since you cannot send direct device-to-device messages with Firebase Cloud Messaging, an alternative for some developers is to use the Firebase Database for keeping a queue of the messages. You'll still need an app server to read that queue and [send the downstream messages to the devices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#http_post_request), but at least you won't have to learn XMPP.